# Php login that doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

What's wrong in this code? I need to make users able to login to this page with facebook account with php and then ther need to be alble to see theyr albums, but login doesn't work. Where is the error in this code? Please help me! Thanks

I've tryed other login script but no one works.

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxx',
'secret' => 'xxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'http://www.photoworld.it?logoutfb'));
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>'http://www.photoworld.it/facebooksdk/load-albums.php'));
}




?>

<?php if ($me): ?>
<?php echo "Welcome, ".$me['first_name']. ".<br />"; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
<img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
<img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
</a>
<?php endif ?>
<?php

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();


if($user_id) {


echo $me['name'] . "<br/>";
echo $me['username']. "<br/><br/>";


$fql = "SELECT aid, name, photo_count, cover_object_id FROM album WHERE owner = '{$user_id}'";

$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => $fql,
));

$total_albums = sizeof($ret_obj);


echo $total_albums . " album totali.<br/><br/>";

for($i=0;$i<$total_albums;$i++)
{
echo "<a href='?aid=" . $ret_obj[$i]['aid'] . "'>" . $ret_obj[$i]['name'] . " (" . $ret_obj[$i]['photo_count'] . ")</a><br/>";
}
}

if (isset($_GET['aid'])) {

echo("<br/><br/>Immagini dell'album selezionato<br/><br/>");

$fql2 = "SELECT pid,src_small,src_big,src FROM photo WHERE aid=" . $_GET['aid'] . "";

$ret_obj2 = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => $fql2,
));
$total_photos = sizeof($ret_obj2);


for($i=0;$i<$total_photos;$i++)
{
echo "<a href='" . $ret_obj2[$i]['src_big'] . "'><img src='" . $ret_obj2[$i]['src'] . "'></a><br/><br/>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work, you need to be more specific with an error message perhaps.

Comment: No, there is not an error message, but when i click on login button it returns to the same page without doing login... I see always the login button and never the informations for logged users ( as the user name or the list of albums of the second part of my code )

Answer (score 0):

`$me` is never really defined, so you will always get the login URL based on your conditionals. You either meant to use `$user` or `$user_profile`